# OpenGLを使ったコンピュータグラフィック

Tags: c++, c, opengl

各頂点に対して， 隣接する頂点の平均位置に向かって移動させることで多面体の形状を滑らかにしていくプログラムを完成させたいです。キーボードで's'を入力するごとに形状が滑らかになっていきます。
しかし、's'を入力しても滑らかにはなりません。load_object内が間違っていると思われるのですが、改善点がわかりません。load_object内でどのようなことが行われており、隣接する頂点を格納していく方法を教えていただきたいです。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(MACOSX)
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#define WINDOW_SIZE      (512)
#define MAX_VERTICES     (16384)
#define MAX_EDGES        (16384)
#define MAX_FACES        (16384)
#define MAX_CORNERS      (64)
#define MAX_ADJS     (32)

#define LAMBDA          (0.6307)
#define MU              (LAMBDA/(0.1*LAMBDA-1.0))
#define NO_INDEX        (-1)

static int width        = WINDOW_SIZE;
static int height       = WINDOW_SIZE;

#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(MACOSX)
int isRetina = 0;
#endif
typedef struct {
   double v[ 3 ];      // 3D coordinates
 int nAdjs;          // number of adjacent vertices
   int adj[ MAX_ADJS ];        // adjacent vertex IDs
} coord;
typedef struct {
   int vidO;           // origin vertex ID of the edge
   int vidD;           // destination vertex ID of the edge
   int fidL;           // left face ID
   int fidR;           // right face ID
} winged;

// structure for a face
typedef struct {
   int vid[ MAX_CORNERS ];
                       // IDs of vertices on the face
                       // (Note that this data structure is
                       // redundant. Retaining a pointer to 
                       // an edge on the face is sufficient.
   int nV;             // number of vertices on the face
} facet;

// vertices
int nVertices = 0;
coord vertex[ MAX_VERTICES ];
// edges
int nEdges = 0;
winged edge[ MAX_EDGES ];
// faces
int nFaces = 0;
facet face[ MAX_FACES ];

// angles of incidence and azimuth
double incidence        = 45.0;
double azimuth          = 30.0;
// aspect ratio
double aspect           =  1.0;
// distance between the eye and origin
double distance         =  6.0;

// flags for mouse button ON/OFF (OFF = 0, ON = 1)
int left_mouse = 0, middle_mouse = 0, right_mouse = 0;
// previous coordinates of the mouse pointer
int last_pointer_x, last_pointer_y;

// search an existing edge
static int search_edge( int orig, int dest )
{
   int i;           // loop counter

   for ( i = 0; i < nEdges; i++ )
    if ( ( edge[ i ].vidO == orig ) && ( edge[ i ].vidD == dest ) )
        return i;
   // If the edge cannot be found, return NO_INDEX
   return NO_INDEX;
}

// load an object
void load_object( char * filename )
{
   int i, j, k;        // loop counters
   FILE * fp_r = NULL;  // file pointer
   char buf[ 256 ];     // temporary buffer
   int nCorners = 0;
   int corner[ MAX_CORNERS ];
                               // array of corner vertex IDs

   // initialize the global variables
   nVertices = nEdges = nFaces = 0;

   // open the file
   if ( ( fp_r = fopen( filename, "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
       fprintf( stderr, "cannot open the file: %s\n", filename );
       return;
   }

   // load the number of vertices
   fgets( buf, sizeof( buf ), fp_r );
   sscanf( buf, "%d", &nVertices );
   fprintf( stderr, "Number of vertices = %d\n", nVertices );
   if ( nVertices > MAX_VERTICES ) {
       fprintf( stderr, "Too many vertices\n" );
       return;
   }

   // load coordinates of each vertex
   for ( i = 0; i < nVertices; i++ ) {
       fgets( buf, sizeof( buf ), fp_r );
       sscanf( buf, "%lf %lf %lf",
        &( vertex[ i ].v[ 0 ] ), &( vertex[ i ].v[ 1 ] ), &( vertex[ i ].v[ 2 ] ) );
    vertex[ i ].nAdjs = 0;
   }

   // load the number of faces
   fgets( buf, sizeof( buf ), fp_r );
   sscanf( buf, "%d", &nFaces );
   if ( nFaces > MAX_FACES ) {
       fprintf( stderr, "Too many faces\n" );
       nFaces = 0;
   }

   // load corner vertices of each face
   for ( i = 0; i < nFaces; i++ ) {

       // load the number of edges for each face
       fgets( buf, sizeof( buf ), fp_r );
       sscanf( buf, "%d", &nCorners );
       // load the corner vertex IDs of each face
       fgets( buf, sizeof( buf ), fp_r );
       k = 0;
       for ( j = 0; j < nCorners; j++ ) {
           while ( ( buf[ k ] == ' ' || buf[ k ] == '\t' ) ) k++;
           sscanf( &( buf[ k ] ), "%d", &( corner[ j ] ) );
           while ( ( '0' <= buf[ k ] ) && ( buf[ k ] <= '9' ) ) k++;
       }

       // generate winged-edge data elements
       for ( j = 0; j < nCorners; j++ ) {
           face[ i ].vid[ j ] = corner[ j ];
           int eidT = search_edge( corner[ (j+1)%nCorners ], corner[ j ] );
           // If the counter part does not exist, generate a new edge.
           if ( eidT == NO_INDEX ) {
               int prevID, nextID;
               prevID = corner[ j ];
               nextID = corner[ (j+1)%nCorners ];
               edge[ nEdges ].vidO = prevID;
               edge[ nEdges ].vidD = nextID;
               edge[ nEdges ].fidL = i;
               nEdges++;
               // For each vertex, register its adjacent vertices
    　

            
        
         }
           // Otherwise, the opposite face of an existing edge
           else {
               edge[ eidT ].fidR = i;
           }
       }
    // generate a new face
    face[ i ].nV = nCorners;
   }

   fclose( fp_r );

   fprintf( stderr, "Number of edges = %d\n", nEdges );
   #ifdef DEBUG
   for ( i = 0; i < nEdges; ++i ) {
    fprintf( stderr,
         "Edge No. %3d is incident to Faces No. %3d and No. %3d\n",
         i, edge[ i ].fidL, edge[ i ].fidR );
   }
   #endif // DEBUG
   fprintf( stderr, "Number of faces = %d\n", nFaces );
   #ifdef DEBUG
   for ( i = 0; i < nFaces; ++i ) {
       fprintf( stderr, "Face No. %3d has Vertices ", i );
       for ( j = 0; j < face[ i ].nV; ++j ) {
           fprintf( stderr, "No. %3d", face[ i ].vid[ j ] );
           if ( j == face[ i ].nV - 2 ) fprintf( stderr, " and " );
           else if ( j == face[ i ].nV - 1 ) fprintf( stderr, "." );
           else fprintf( stderr, ", " );
       }
       fprintf( stderr, "\n" );
   }
   #endif // DEBUG
}
void weighted_average( double weight )
{
   // temporary storage for coordinates
   static coord newcoord[ MAX_VERTICES ];
   // loop counters
   int i, j, k;

   // for each vertex
   for ( i = 0; i < nVertices; ++i ) {
       // average color of neighboring faces
       coord ave;
       // for each neighboring faces
       for ( k = 0; k < 3; ++k ) ave.v[ k ] = 0.0;

       // for each adjacent vertex
       for ( j = 0; j < vertex[ i ].nAdjs; ++j ) {
           int idAdj = vertex[ i ].adj[ j ];
           for ( k = 0; k < 3; ++k )
               ave.v[ k ] += vertex[ idAdj ].v[ k ];
       }
       for ( k = 0; k < 3; ++k )
           ave.v[ k ] /= ( double )vertex[ i ].nAdjs;

       for ( k = 0; k < 3; ++k )
           newcoord[ i ].v[ k ] =
               ( 1.0 - weight ) * vertex[ i ].v[ k ] + weight * ave.v[ k ];
   }

   // copy back the new coordinates
   for ( i = 0; i < nVertices; ++i ) {
       for ( k = 0; k < 3; ++k )
           vertex[ i ].v[ k ] = newcoord[ i ].v[ k ];
   }
}

void update_position( void )
{
   weighted_average( LAMBDA );
   weighted_average( MU );
}

// draw the object 
void draw_object( void )
{
   // loop counters
   int i, j;

   // set the line width
   glLineWidth( 1.0 );
// draw a list of edges
   // set the color of the edges
   glColor3d( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
   // set rasterization type and polygon facing
   glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );
   // for each face
   for ( i = 0; i < nFaces; ++i ) {
       // outline the face
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
    // for each corner vertex
    for ( j = 0; j < face[ i ].nV; ++j ) {
        glVertex3dv( vertex[ face[ i ].vid[ j ] ].v );
    }
    glEnd();
   }

   // hide the invisible lines by filling the face with the background color
   // set the color of the face
   glColor3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
   // set rasterization type and polygon facing
   glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL );
   // enable polygon offset to avoid conflict with the polygon outlines
   glEnable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL );
   glPolygonOffset( 1.0, 2.0 );
   // for each face
   for ( i = 0; i < nFaces; ++i ) {
       // fill the face
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
    // for each corner vertex
    for ( j = 0; j < face[ i ].nV; ++j ) {
        glVertex3dv( vertex[ face[ i ].vid[ j ] ].v );
    }
    glEnd();
   }
   glDisable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL );

}
void display( void )
{
   glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
   glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
   glLoadIdentity();
   glTranslated( 0.0, 0.0, -distance );
   glRotated( -incidence, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
   glRotated( -azimuth, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
   draw_object();
   glutSwapBuffers();
}
void reshape( int w, int h )
{
   width = w;
   height = h;
#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(MACOSX)
   if ( isRetina ) {
    width = w*2;
    height = h*2;
   }
#endif
   glViewport ( 0, 0, width, height ); 
   glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
   glLoadIdentity ();
   aspect = ( double )w/( double )h;
   gluPerspective( 65.0, aspect, 0.1, 100.0 );
}
void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
  switch ( key ) {
    case 'q':
    case 'Q':
    case '\033':  // ASCII code of ESC
        exit( 0 );
        break;
    case '8':
        load_object( "horse.dat" );
        break;
    case 's':
        update_position();
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
void init( void )
{
#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(MACOSX)
   int originalViewport[ 4 ];
   glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, originalViewport );
   if ( ( originalViewport[ 2 ] == WINDOW_SIZE * 2 ) &&
     ( originalViewport[ 3 ] == WINDOW_SIZE * 2 ) ) {
    fprintf( stderr, " Retina display!!\n" );
    isRetina = 1;
   }
   else {
    fprintf( stderr, " NOT Retina display!!\n" );
    isRetina = 0;
   }
#endif
   glClearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
   glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
   glEnable( GL_CULL_FACE );
   glCullFace( GL_BACK );
}

// main function
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   glutInit( &argc, argv );
   glutInitWindowPosition( 50, 50 );
   glutInitWindowSize( WINDOW_SIZE, WINDOW_SIZE );
   glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH );
   glutCreateWindow( argv[0] );
   glutDisplayFunc( display );
   glutReshapeFunc( reshape );
   glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );
   init();
   glutMainLoop();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `horse.dat`ファイルの内容も示してください。問題の再現・調査が出来ないと思われます。加えて参考にした書籍・記事・資料や、やりたい事の内容・方向性といったものが書かれている記事なども追記してみてください。

Comment: さすがにソースコードの量も多く、[もう少しコードを短くしてもらう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)かどのようなデバッグをしてload_object内が間違っていると判断したのかも書いてもらえるとよいでしょう。